# How do I take the data from a .json file, use only some of the items in it, and populate a combobox with that data?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, winforms, json.net

What I'm looking to do is take my .json file, grab only certain items from that file, and then populate the items in a combobox with that filtered data (using Newtonsoft / Json.net). I'll give you an example:

(some of the) JSON File Data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Kerbol",
    "radius": 261600000,
    "mass": 1.7565670e+28
  },
  {
    "name": "Moho",
    "radius": 250000,
    "mass": 2.5263617e+21
  },
  {
    "name": "Eve",
    "radius": 700000,
    "mass": 1.2244127e+23
  },
]
```

This isn't all of the data, just some of it. It's some info on the planets in the game "Kerbal Space Program". The only thing I'm interested in (right now) is only grabbing every "name" item in the .json file. Then I want to populate the items property in a combobox with all of those names (on each line).

I've tried a lot of other code to filter it out, but I don't understand enough to rewrite it to work how I need.

EDIT: I want to do more with this .json data later on, but I'm just trying to do this one step at a time.

EDIT2: This is for Windows Forms.

Comment: Show what code you've tried so far.

Comment: Is this WinForms, ASP.net or WPF?

Comment: Nkosi,
I deleted it all, so I can't help you there.

Brian Rogers,
It's WinForms. I'll edit this into the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a wpf demo, i have test it on my computer, you can try.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var data = MyModel.getTestData();
        var dataStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"d:\data.json", false))
        {
            writer.Write(dataStr);
        }
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"d:\data.json"))
        {
            var recs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyModel>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            cbx.ItemsSource = recs;//cbx is ComboBox
            cbx.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
            cbx.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

public class MyModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double radius { get; set; }
    public double  mass  { get; set; }

    public static List<MyModel> getTestData()
    {
        return new List<MyModel>
        {
            new MyModel {name = "x1", radius = 1, mass = 1},
            new MyModel {name = "x2", radius = 2, mass = 2},
            new MyModel {name = "x3", radius = 3, mass = 3},
            new MyModel {name = "x4", radius = 4, mass = 4},
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find some people on Discord who I could talk to, so that helped a lot better. Pretty much every piece of code I ever saw trying to look this up was unhelpful for me as I didn't understand it enough to salvage it. So here's what it eventually ended up being:

celestialbodydata.cs

```
using System;

namespace KMAP
{
    class CelestialBodyData
    {
        public string name { get; protected set; }
        public double radius { get; protected set; }
        public double mass { get; protected set; }

        public CelestialBodyData(string name, double radius, double mass)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.radius = radius;
            this.mass = mass;
        }
    }
}
```

Main Form.cs:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SemMajAxTab_InputBodyRadius_ComboBox.Items.Clear();
    OPTab_InputBodyMass_ComboBox.Items.Clear();
    OPTab_InputBodyMass2_ComboBox.Items.Clear();
    OPTab_InputBodyRadius_ComboBox.Items.Clear();
    HohTab_InputBodyMass_ComboBox1.Items.Clear();
    HohTab_InputBodyRadius_ComboBox1.Items.Clear();
    HohTab_InputBodyMass_ComboBox2.Items.Clear();
    HohTab_InputBodyRadius_ComboBox4.Items.Clear();

    CelestialBodyData[] celestialbodydata_Array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CelestialBodyData[]>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Anase\Desktop\Visual C\KMAP\KMAP\bin\Release\celestialbodydata.json"));

    string[] namesarray = new string[celestialbodydata_Array.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < celestialbodydata_Array.Length; i++)
    {
        namesarray[i] = (celestialbodydata_Array[i].name).ToString();
    }

    SemMajAxTab_InputBodyRadius_ComboBox.Items.AddRange(namesarray);
    OPTab_InputBodyMass_ComboBox.Items.AddRange(namesarray);
    OPTab_InputBodyMass2_ComboBox.Items.AddRange(namesarray);
    OPTab_InputBodyRadius_ComboBox.Items.AddRange(namesarray);
    HohTab_InputBodyMass_ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(namesarray);
    HohTab_InputBodyRadius_ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(namesarray);
    HohTab_InputBodyMass_ComboBox2.Items.AddRange(namesarray);
    HohTab_InputBodyRadius_ComboBox4.Items.AddRange(namesarray);
}
```

It's a lot simpler than a lot of other stuff I've seen. The hard part is going to be getting it so that when you click on an item in the combobox, it searches the array for that name and then grabs the adjacent mass or radius value and replaces the combobox's text with that. I'm new to loops and arrays.

Comment: if you trying to read a property which doesn't exist it will return stackoverflow exception in the case of deserialize code (which is part of newtonsoft.json)

Comment: @GuptaAnirudha I don't know what that means, nor what to do with that information. Please keep in mind that I only started learning visual C# a bit over a month ago, and before that, I know very little about coding in general (nothing beyond basic lua coding in World of Warcraft's API making WeakAuras).